# Javascript detect 10 minutes before variable time

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript, how to check the current time is lower than 10 minutes from variable `nextTime`?

```
var currentTime = "11:25:00";
var nextTime = "11:35:00";

if(currentTime <= nextTime)
{
    alert("test");
}
```

If I do like code above, time before 11:35:00 it always alert me.

What I want detect 10 minutes before `nextTime`, so it will always alert once.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the string always going to be formatted like that?

Comment: @Skam Yes always like that

Comment: Convert both times to minutes (or seconds) since "00:00:00", then it's just a matter of subtracting two integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using moment.js . Here is example

```js
var currentTime = "11:25:00";
var nextTime = "11:35:00";
var startTime=moment(currentTime, "HH:mm:ss");
var endTime=moment(nextTime, "HH:mm:ss");

var diffrent = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));

var hours = parseInt(diffrent.asHours());
var minutes = parseInt(diffrent.asMinutes())-hours*60;
var totalMin=(hours*60)+minutes


if(totalMin==10){
 alert(true)
}else{
  alert('Minutes is != 10 minutes!')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.19.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I think it will helpful to you.

Comment: How about 10 minutes before nextTime? Only 10 minutes before

Comment: Why one needs to download another library for simple calculation

Answer (score 1):

```
// convert hh:mm:ss string to seconds
const hhmmssToSeconds = ( timestr ) => {
  const time = timestr.split(':');
  time[0] = parseInt( time[0] ) * 3600; // hours to seconds
  time[1] = parseInt( time[1] ) * 60;  // minutes to seconds
  time[2] = parseInt( time[2] ); // seconds :)

  // return sum of seconds
  return time.reduce( (acc, val) => acc + val );
}

// difference in seconds
const timeDifference = ( timeA, timeB ) => {
    return hhmmssToSeconds( timeA ) - hhmmssToSeconds( timeB );
}

const isTenMinutes = ( timeA, timeB ) => {
    return timeDifference( timeA, timeB ) === 600;
}

console.log( isTenMinutes( "11:35:00", "11:24:00" ) );  // false
console.log( isTenMinutes( "11:35:00", "11:25:00" ) );  // true
console.log( isTenMinutes( "11:35:00", "11:26:00" ) );  // false
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cd271oh7/1/

Comment: 3606 to 3600  -- this might be big processing ( not time wise ) code lenght wise

Comment: Sorry, the `3606` was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Define the epoc Date
var epocTime="Thu Jan 01 1970";

(Date.parse(epocTime + " " + nextTime) - Date.parse(epocTime + " " + currentTime))/(1000*10*60) --> should be >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out,

```js
<script>
var currentTime = "11:25:00"
var nextTime = "11:35:00";
var date1 = new Date("2000-01-02T"+currentTime);
var date2 = new Date("2000-01-02T"+nextTime);
if(date1.getMinutes() <= (date2.getMinutes()-10))
{
    alert("test");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works only if you refresh the browser just ten miunets before specified time:

```
    var specifiedTime = new Date("November 02, 2017 05:56:00");
    var specifiedTimeMinutes = specifiedTime.getMinutes();

    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentTimeMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes(); 


if(specifiedTimeMinutes-currentTimeMinutes==10)
{
    alert("test");
}
```

Do you need to make it automaticaly without refreshing the browser?

Comment: This will also be true if the difference is one hour and ten minutes. Or 2:10, etc.

Comment: that's correct. Thank you for pointing that out. I would recommend to extend above using .getHours() method to make sure it is on the same hour.

Comment: You could just use `if(currentTime - specifiedTime == 10 * 60 * 1000)` (subtracting two Date objects will give you the difference in milliseconds)

Comment: that's true but I prefer using dedicated functions as the code is more redable to me afterwards.